# NestJs - Nats call mocking with jest

Tags: jestjs, mocking, nestjs, nats.io

I have to create jest unit test for some services in nestJS in which sub e pub nats calls are used. I googled a lot but I didn't find a solution so far. Do you have any idea how to mock nats pub and sub calls? Which Is the best approach to achieve this?